# Can't modify UART 5 baudrate

Tags: uart, config.txt

I'm trying to communicate a NUCLEO-F746ZG with a RPi-CM4 thru the UART5.
I need, at least, a baudrate >= 4000000.
Using the stty -F /dev/ttyAMA2 4000000 I get the *"unable to perform all requested operations"* message.
Searching I found different approaches to test in the "/boot/config.txt" file but, so far, nothing works for me

- init_uart_clock=64000000. Dosn't modify anything, and reading the reference manual I found that this works only for the UART0. The others UARTx are related to the Clock Manager.
- force_turbo=1. Can't set this dtoverlay command.
- Trying to modify the IBDR, FBDR and LCRH registers using C, gives me segmentation fault.

Have any suggestion?

This is the code I run to try to modify the registers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>


#define UART5_ADDR  0x7E201A00      // UART5 Base Address
#define IBRD        0x25            // Integer Baud Rate Divisor
#define FBRD        0x28            // Fractional Baud Rate Divisor
#define LCRH        0x2C            // Line Control Register

// Macros
#define READ_REG(val)   (*(volatile uint32_t *)(UART5_ADDR + val))
#define WRITE_REG(offset, val)   ((*(volatile uint32_t *)(UART5_ADDR + offset)) = (val))

#define MAPPED_FILE_SIZE    (50 * sizeof(int))

void *mapped_region, *mapped_reg;
off_t dev_base = (UART5_ADDR | IBRD);
int mfd;

int main(void)
{
    mfd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR | O_SYNC);
    if(-1 == mfd)
    {
        printf("No se puede abrir.\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    mapped_region = mmap(NULL, MAPPED_FILE_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, mfd, dev_base);
    mapped_reg = mapped_region + dev_base;
    printf("IBRD = %x.\n", *((uint32_t*)mapped_reg));
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you need 4,000,000 and not 400,000? 4Mbit is extemely fast for a serial link.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, I'm sure.